# Hey! I'm trying to try out all of the possibilities with linked lists in C, but when I try to remove the first item (pop), I keep getting an error

Tags: c, linked-list, atom-editor

Here is my code, and the problem is with the function `pop`

In this program I'm just creating a linked list, with two values, 1 and 2. Then I simply print the list, and then I print again, but after running the pop function. However, I keep running into this warning/error. I would really appreciate if  you could help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int val;
    struct node* next;
}
node;

//Print list
void print_list(node * header) {
    node * current = header;

    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", current->val);
        current = current->next;
    }
}

//Removing from the list (pop)
int pop(node** header)
{
  if (*header == NULL)
  {
    return -1;
  }

  node* next_node = *header;
  int retvalue = next_node->val;

  (*header) = (*header)->next;

  free(next_node);

  return retvalue;
}


int main(void)
{
  //Alllocating the header of the list
  node *header = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));

  //Making sure header doesn't return NULL
  if (header == NULL)
  {
    return 1;
  }

  header->val = 1;
  header->next = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
  header->next->val = 2;
  header->next->next = NULL;

  printf("Here is the first list:\n");
  print_list(header);
  printf("Here is the list with a removed value (start)(pop):\n");
  pop(header);
  print_list(header);


}
```

This is the error I get from my compiler:

```
warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'node *' (aka 'struct node *') to parameter of type

      'node **' (aka 'struct node **'); take the address with & [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  pop(header);
      ^~~~~~
      &
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `pop()` function takes a *pointer to a pointer*, you must pass in one as such:

```
pop(&header);
```

This is presumably because the function may need to change that pointer and needs direct access to it as a mutable argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'node *' (aka 'struct node *') to parameter of type
'node **' (aka 'struct node **'); take the address with & [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  pop(header);
      ^~~~~~
      &
```

Your compiler error explains everything.
The function `int pop(node** header)` accepts `address of a pointer of type node` as its argument and you are just sending the `value of header` which is a `pointer to the location allocation by malloc`.

So, change `pop(header)` to `pop(&header)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you pass a `node*` to `pop` function that accepts `node**`, you just need to pass `&header` in order to get it working.

Such tiny mistakes can be avoided when using static analyzer, it immediately highlights problematic code.